# How to use log scale to show proper stacked bar chart using d3 JS?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display stak chart using d3 js.  I also tried with log scale but did not get to work.

**Aug month** staked bar not visible properly or there may be more cases like this.

**How to make it visible properly  using log scale?**

```
var margins = {
top: 12,
left: 48,
right: 24,
bottom: 24
},
legendPanel = {
width: 180
},
width = 500 - margins.left - margins.right - legendPanel.width,
height = 100 - margins.top - margins.bottom,
dataset = [{
    data: [{
        month: 'Aug',
        count: 1
    }, {
        month: 'feb',
        count: 234
    }, {
        month: 'mar',
        count: 345
    }],
    name: 'Series #1'
}, {
    data: [{
        month: 'Aug',
        count: 3
    }, {
        month: 'feb',
        count: 267
    }, {
        month: 'mar',
        count: 573
    }],
    name: 'Series #2'
},
{
    data: [{
        month: 'Aug',
        count: 20
    }, {
        month: 'feb',
        count: 267
    }, {
        month: 'mar',
        count: 573
    }],
    name: 'Series #3'
}

],
series = dataset.map(function (d) {
    return d.name;
}),
dataset = dataset.map(function (d) {
    return d.data.map(function (o, i) {
        // Structure it so that your numeric
        // axis (the stacked amount) is y
        return {
            y: o.count,
            x: o.month
        };
    });
}),
stack = d3.layout.stack();

stack(dataset);

var dataset = dataset.map(function (group) {
return group.map(function (d) {
    // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
    return {
        x: d.y,
        y: d.x,
        x0: d.y0
    };
});
}),
  svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right + legendPanel.width)
    .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')'),
xMax = d3.max(dataset, function (group) {
    return d3.max(group, function (d) {
        return d.x + d.x0;
    });
}),
xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, xMax])
    .range([0, width]),
months = dataset[0].map(function (d) {
    return d.y;
}),
_ = console.log(months),
yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(months)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1),
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom'),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient('left'),
colours = d3.scale.category10(),
groups = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .style('fill', function (d, i) {
    return colours(i);
}),
rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {
    return d;
})
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
    return xScale(d.x0);
})
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
    return yScale(d.y);
})
    .attr('height', function (d) {
    return yScale.rangeBand();
})
    .attr('width', function (d) {
    return xScale(d.x);
})
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
    var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x')) / 2 + width / 2;
    var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2;

    d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style('left', xPos + 'px')
        .style('top', yPos + 'px')
        .select('#value')
        .text(d.x);

    d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
})
    .on('mouseout', function () {
    d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', true);
})

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

 svg.append('g')
.attr('class', 'axis')
.call(yAxis);

svg.append('rect')
.attr('fill', 'yellow')
.attr('width', 160)
.attr('height', 30 * dataset.length)
.attr('x', width + margins.left)
.attr('y', 0);

series.forEach(function (s, i) {
svg.append('text')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .attr('x', width + margins.left + 8)
    .attr('y', i * 24 + 24)
    .text(s);
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('fill', colours(i))
    .attr('width', 60)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('x', width + margins.left + 90)
    .attr('y', i * 24 + 6);
});
```

sample code  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBfy5/1577/)

Comment: Could you please reduce your code snippet to a MCVE, clearly showing the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in log-scale in d3, but some more modifications are needed.
The first thing you need to do is change your xScale to be logarithmic:

```
xScale = d3.scale.log()
        .domain([0.5, xMax])//The x-min can not be 0!
        .range([0, width]),
```

Note that xmin is 0.5 instead of 0. Because 0 can not exist in a logarithmic scale. And putting anything larger than 1 would make the Series #1 of august not visable since it is 1.

The second thing you need is to calculate the width in a different way since your scale is not linear anymore, i.e. 10->20 is wider than 110->120:

```
.attr('width', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x0+d.x)- (d.x0==0 ? 0 : xScale(d.x0));
    })
```

This simply takes the position of the end-point `(d.x0+d.x)` and subtract the position of the startpoint `d.x0`. Not that if `d.x0 == 0`, 0 is used as start-pos since 0 do not exist in xScale

And finaly, default is to show ticks as `1e+02` for example, so change the format for the tick by

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(0, '.1s'),
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBfy5/1581/)

Comment: But other stacked bar are not according to its values like 1st **mar** count is 345 is wider than next count values which are 573 and  573.  staked bar should be visible according to its count values.

Comment: I can understand it is showing according  **xAxis ticks** and  log scale. and How to hide or remove xAxis and yAxis lines(show only yAxis title like feb,mar,Aug etc.)

Comment: I am not sure what you want to visualize or how it is used. But mayby it is better to have the proportion for each month, for examle blue = 20%, orange = 40% and green = 40%. This way all month will have a total-bar that is 100% wide. And when you hover you can display the actual count? Something similar to: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent

Comment: Can we show width of each bar stacked according to its count of each month similar to (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) ?. In this each bar width is according to its values .Ex- Jane 2 < Joe 3 < john 5 you can see width of each Apples Bar

Comment: I thought your problem was that augusts count was so small that is was not visiblie since april and march was so large and thats why you wanted to use a logarithmic scale. It is hard to make all values visible and maintain a linear scale where the width of each bar is according to its value.